Three.js sprite in mapbox combine
mapbox-gl-js version: 3.4.3
browser: chrome 126
Steps to Trigger Behavior
I used the example Add a 3D model use threejs of official website to add sprite, but the display is not correct and I can't face the camera.
In Three.js, i trying to add a sprite and it's not facing the camera
sprite not work like a plane
example
const customLayer = {
        id: '3d-model',
        type: 'custom',
        renderingMode: '3d',
        onAdd: function (map, gl) {
            this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
            this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
            directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
            this.scene.add(directionalLight);
            const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/sprite0.png');
            let material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: texture ,side:THREE.DoubleSide});
            material.sizeAttenuation = false;
            let sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
            sprite.scale.set(100, 100, 1)
            this.scene.add(sprite);
          
            this.map = map;

            // use the Mapbox GL JS map canvas for three.js
            this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                canvas: map.getCanvas(),
                context: gl,
                antialias: true
            });

            this.renderer.autoClear = false;
        },
        render: function (gl, matrix) {
            const rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
                new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
                modelTransform.rotateX
            );
            const rotationY = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
                modelTransform.rotateY
            );
            const rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
                modelTransform.rotateZ
            );

            const m = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);
            const l = new THREE.Matrix4()
                .makeTranslation(
                    modelTransform.translateX,
                    modelTransform.translateY,
                    modelTransform.translateZ
                )
                .scale(
                    new THREE.Vector3(
                        modelTransform.scale,
                        -modelTransform.scale,
                        modelTransform.scale
                    )
                )
                .multiply(rotationX)
                .multiply(rotationY)
                .multiply(rotationZ);

            this.camera.projectionMatrix = m.multiply(l);
            this.renderer.resetState();
            this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
            this.map.triggerRepaint();
        }```


link  example
